# .htaccess mod_rewrite: enabling caching via checking if file exists

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, caching, mod-rewrite

I am implementing a caching system for dynamically generated images. The script is called via `/img/type/param1/param2.png`, where multiple types are possible and the number of parameters are variable. The script generates the image and dumps it to disk.

I would like `.htaccess` rules, which when requesting the image generation script:

1. checks to see if a cached file exists
2. if so, mod_rewrite to the cached file
3. if not, don't do anything so that the script runs

What I have so far is a slightly modified logic:

1. mod_rewrite to where the cached file would be
2. check to see if the file exists
3. if not, mod_rewrite the request back again

If there's a better way to do this, I'd love to hear it. In any case, the relevant part of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^img/(type1|type2)/(.*)$ /images/cache/$1/$2

RewriteCond /^(.*)$ !-f
RewriteRule images/cache/(.*) /img/$1
```

This doesn't seem to work quite right. To debug it, I inserted the following after the first RewriteRule (the target page just dumps its input):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /htaccess.php?url=$1 [END]
```

As a result, I get:

```
Array
(
    [url] => /images/cache/a/l/300.png/a/l/300.png
)
```

I don't understand why `$2` contains `l/300.png/a/l/300.png` instead of just `l/300.png`.

If I change first RewriteRule to include an `[L]`, I get the expected result. However, I experience the exact same "double-matching" issue on the second RewriteRule which reverts the request back into the non-cache version. However, adding `[L]` to this second RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^img/(type1|type2)/(.*)$ /images/cache/$1/$2 [L]

RewriteCond /^(.*)$ !-f
RewriteRule images/cache/(.*) /img/$1 [L]
```

yields an Internal Server Error.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first logic that you have is what you want to be doing, that bypasses the possible looping issues. You just need to extract the relevant bits from the `%{REQUEST_URI}` then backreference them using `%` references. So for example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/img/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/cache/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ /images/cache/$1 [L]
```

or using the regex patterns that you had:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/img/(type1|type2)/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/cache/%1/%2 -f
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ /images/cache/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much. For my own edification, why weren't my attempts working?

Comment: @Mala I'm not 100% sure, but you probably want to replace `RewriteCond /^(.*)$ !-f` with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` since the new URI is the /images/cache one